# Google Calendar. Is there a way to hide morning hours for the iframe widget? Similar to the "hide morning and night" lab

Tags: iframe, time, calendar, embed

When all of my events are 9 a.m. onwards and i embed an iframe widget in my site, the users have to scroll down to see the events. A way to hide the early morning hours from the calendar widget would really make it a lot more usable. Is it possible?

Sometimes people ask if setting a certain displayed date is possible. The answer is yes. It is done through modifying an <.iframe.> parameter called

```
ctz=Europe%2FMoscow
```

to

```
ctz=Europe%2FMoscow&dates=20130408/20130412
```

So if that's possible, may be there is a parameter to set to make it display timespan from  9 a.m. to 5 p.m.
Or at least to make calendar start at day time.

Here's the live presentation of what I am talking about:
(if the question is going to be answered I'll try to keep the link alive for future generations, so you go try it in the year 2013++)

http://center-president.ru/page212.html